# Pretty print by default in Python REPL

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

How can i enable pretty print on the REPL by default?

Currently I do it by using `pprint.pprint()` function.

```
>>> pprint.pprint(data)
{'SHIP_CATEGORY': '',
 'SHIP_QUANTITY': 1,
 'SHIP_SEPARATELY': 0,
 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT': 0,
 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE': 0,
 'THUMBNAIL': ''}
```

But I want pretty print by default

```
>>> data
{'SHIP_CATEGORY': '',
 'SHIP_QUANTITY': 1,
 'SHIP_SEPARATELY': 0,
 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT': 0,
 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE': 0,
 'THUMBNAIL': ''}
```

What have I tried?
I searched on google. Didn't found anything most result points to `pprint` module

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [sys.displayhook](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys#sys.displayhook)

```
import pprint
import sys

orig_displayhook = sys.displayhook

def myhook(value):
    if value != None:
        __builtins__._ = value
        pprint.pprint(value)

__builtins__.pprint_on = lambda: setattr(sys, 'displayhook', myhook)
__builtins__.pprint_off = lambda: setattr(sys, 'displayhook', orig_displayhook)
```

Put Above code to [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) if you don't want type it every time you run interactive shell.

### Usage:

```
>>> data = dict.fromkeys(range(10))
>>> data
{0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}
>>> pprint_on()
>>> data
{0: None,
 1: None,
 2: None,
 3: None,
 4: None,
 5: None,
 6: None,
 7: None,
 8: None,
 9: None}
>>> pprint_off()
>>> data
{0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve it on the runtime instead of start up time? The reason is I am debugging something very big. And I have loaded a lot of thing by literally writing in the shell.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, I updated the code. Use `pprint_on()`/`pprint_off()`

Comment: What's the reason for setting `__builtins__._ = value` in the custom hook?

Comment: @l4mpi, default `sys.displayhook` do that. So I mimiced that behavior.

Comment: @l4mpi, try `help(sys.displayhook)`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Still doesn't explain _why_ it does this, I'll search the mailing lists a bit to see if there's a more detailed explanation for this...

Comment: @l4mpi, Don't you use `_` in interactive shell? `_` refers to last result.

Comment: When I try to use `__builtins__._` I get: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_'`. When I use `__builtins__['_']` it works fine.

Comment: @Joe, May I ask you what implementation and which version of Python you use?

Comment: @Joe, Never mind. [Python 2 \_\_builtin__ module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html), [Python 3 builtins module documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) mention that. *Most modules have the name \__builtins__ (note the 's') made available as part of their globals. The value of \__builtins__ is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s \__dict__ attribute.*

Comment: No need to save `orig_displayhook`. This is already saved as `sys.__displayhook__`.

Answer (score 11):

Use [IPython](http://ipython.org/) shell:

```
In [10]: data = {'SHIP_CATEGORY': '',  'SHIP_QUANTITY': 1, 'SHIP_SEPARATELY': 0, 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT': 0, 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE': 0,}

In [11]: data
Out[11]: 
{'SHIP_CATEGORY': '',
 'SHIP_QUANTITY': 1,
 'SHIP_SEPARATELY': 0,
 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT': 0,
 'SHIP_SUPPLEMENT_ONCE': 0}
```

It also has an option `--no-pprint` in case you want to disable this pretty printing.

`IPython` shell also has [features](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html) like tab-completion, multi-line paste, run shell commands etc. So, it is quite better than the normal python shell.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [falsetru's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17248483/8630729) accepted answer, but in the form of a one-liner:

```
from pprint import pprint
import sys

sys.displayhook = lambda x: exec(['_=x; pprint(x)','pass'][x is None])
```

and to switch back (based on kyrill's comment):

```
sys.displayhook = sys.__displayhook__
```